# ifilter not working with MOSS 2007, cant crawl .pdf

Tags: sharepoint, pdf

Installed ifilter and followed the guides: 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2008/02/06/configuring-moss-2007-to-search-pdf-documents-install-and-configure-pdf-ifilters.aspx
and the accompanying link to the MS hotfix..

I have initiated multiple crawls that don't show any .pdf documents, let alone the contents of the .pdfs (I did constantly upload test documents with real content).

In the 'file types' menu of the shared servies, it didn't show the pdf icon as I think it was meant to, it also lists 'pdf' as filetype 'AcroExch.Document', is this correct?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @SORRYPROFESSOR: are you on 64-bit SharePoint by any chance?

Comment: Yes why? . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of the PDF ifilter (and instructions...) Try getting the [PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025), and follow the instructions at the bottom of the page for setting it up in SharePoint.